# How to keep Night Shift™ enabled indefinitely on macOS 10.12.5+? Settings only have "turn on until tomorrow"

Tags: macos, night-shift

I want to keep it turned on until I turn it off, not until some fixed date. How to achieve this?

(I know about the option to use f.lux, but I'd prefer to not depend on it now that macOS is so close to being able to do it itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the preferences (System Preferences > Display > Night Shift) do the following:

- set 'Schedule' to Custom
- set 'From:' to 00:00
- set 'to:' to 23:59
- adjust the Color Temperature as desired

Now night shift will be enabled all the time. Disable it using the Notification Center or using the 'Manual' toggle in the preferences pane.

Comment: doesn't work. apparently it decides that the "night" part is the 1-minute interval.

Comment: In this case please try it with two other times like 'from 10:00 to 09:59'. This will activate it for 24:00 hours. The larger time value (10:00) should be in the left. Otherwise it will be activated for just two minutes. :)

Comment: hmm, maybe it doesn't apply the schedule setting immediately and I have to wait 1-2 days

Comment: Is there a solution for that? How to make custom Night Shift settings remain stick forever indefinitely on Mac Sierra?

Comment: For the latest version of Catalina, if I don't tick "Turn On Until Tomorrow" (BTW, the word 'on' should not be uppercased, Apple), it doesn't work. If I do tick it, the next day it's gone. So, this is still a fail.

Comment: People may be still online at 00:00. So 4:00 -> 3:59 should be better.

Comment: what a stupid setting

Answer (score -2):

open Notification Center, swipe down and manualy change.

Comment: That doesn't keep it on forever...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review